# Memory presentation for variants in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

For variants without parameters, they are simply stored as an OCaml integer without boxing and the integers are in ascending order **within one type**.

For example, let's define a function `peek` to see the real integer value of a variant:

```
let peek x = ((Obj.magic (Obj.repr x)):int);;
```

I define a type:

```
type t1 = Apple | Orange;;
```

then `peek Apple;;` will return `0` and `peek Orange;;` will return `1`.

However, if I define 2nd type

```
type t2 = Empty | Node;;
```

then again `peek Empty;;` will return `0` and `1` for `peek Node`.

---

Basically, the increment of the integers for variants are not global.

I have then questions:

1. Since OCaml won't maintain type information during runtime, how can runtime knows an integer being a normal integer or a variant without parameter?
2. Further, how OCaml runtime tell the differences between two variants that actually belong to different types? e.g., how can it tell the diff between *Apple* and *Empty* as they are both 0?

Comment: you will see that exceptions, open-types, and polymorphic variants are different.

Comment: @nlucaroni what do u mean by `open-types`?

Comment: new in ocaml 4.02 -- http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime can't make the difference between `0`, `Apple` and `Empty` but it doesn't need to. The compiler checks the types so that `Apple` will always be used with type `t1` and not `t2` or `int`. Once the types are checked by the compiler, you  no longer need them because you are sure (you have a proof of it) that the integer `0` with the meaning `Apple` with never be used with another meaning.